# Remove objects having Identiaclal name & age properties Only if another property is set to False

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of `Person` objects and I want to remove similar (i.e. having the same `objects from it.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isSelfEmployed;

    // getters, constructor, etc.
}
```

*Sample data:*

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("John", 26, true));    // Include
personList.add(new Person("Erica", 29, false));  // Include
personList.add(new Person("John", 26, false));   // Exclude
```

For `Person` objects having the same `name` and `age` I want to remove only those objects where `isSelfEmployed` property is `false` (i.e. the final list should contain only the first and the second objects).

I'm wonder is it possible to achieve using streams?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/stream-distinct-by-multiple-fields/

Answer (score 1):

We can group `Person` objects by `name` and `age` using *collector* `groupingBy()` that would give a Map with each value represented by a list of namesake people have the same and age.

Then we need to iterate over the *values* of the *map*, applying the logic for eliminating people having property `isSelfEmployed` set to `false` if there's more than one person mapped to the same *key*.

I assume that we can't rely on the implementation of the `equals/hashCode` (it might be implemented differently than based on two fields we're interested in) and in order to group `Person` objects I would use a Java 16 [*record*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) as a *key* (we can also make use of a plain class for that, the option with record is less verbose).

And to implement filtering logic I would use [`mapMulty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) operation, which is meant for one-to-many transformations similarly to `flatMap` and replaces a stream element with zero or more elements of a different type. This operation is also one of the features of Java 16.

```
List<Person> personList = List.of(
    new Person("John", 26, true),
    new Person("Erica", 29, false),
    new Person("John", 26, false)
);
        
List<Person> result = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        person -> {
            record Key(String name, int age) {}
            return new Key(person.getName(), person.getAge());
        }))
    .values().stream()
    .<Person>mapMulti((list, consumer) -> {
        if (list.size() == 1) list.forEach(consumer);
        else list.stream().filter(Person::isSelfEmployed).forEach(consumer);
    })
    .toList();
        
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Person{name='Erica', age=29, isSelfEmployed=false}
Person{name='John', age=26, isSelfEmployed=true}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tUs)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one of those questions which shouldn't be solved using the Stream API.

While [Alexander Ivanchenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73365117/8430155) provides a way to achieve this by using Stream, here is an example with normal loops:

```java
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Person p: personList) {
    // name#age as key
    // assuming `#` will not appear at the end of name or at the beginning of age
    // Using `#` because what is name is John2 and age is 25?
    String k = p.name + "#" + p.age;
    if (map.containsKey(k) && !p.isSelfEmployed) {
        continue;
    }
    map.put(k, p);
}
```

---

A simple, recommended, another approach would be to override `equals` and `hashcode` of `Person` class and simply add the `List` to a `Set` and the overridden methods will determine the uniqueness in the `Set`.